# Input format for Kruskal-Wallis test in Python

Tags: python, arrays, kruskal-wallis

I am comparing regions in the DNA on structural breaks in cancer patients and healthy people. I am trying to run a Kruskal-Wallis test (SciPy Stats) on the number of breaks for each region, to see if there is a difference between the two distributions. 
I am not sure if the input for the Kruskal - Wallis should be arrays (documentation), or a list of arrays (elsewhere on the internet).

First, I tried an array for sample+control like this:

```
controls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
samples = ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']
n=0
for item in controls:
    array_item = np.array([item, samples[n]])
    kw_test = stats.mstats.kruskalwallis(array_item)
    print(kw_test)
    n+=1
```

That gave me the following output for all items:

```
(0.0, nan)
```

I also tried converting the individual datapoints in arrays, and then run the KW-test.

```
controls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
samples = ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']
n=0
kw_results = []
for item in controls:
    array_controls = np.array([item])
    array_samples = np.array([samples[n]])
    kw_test = stats.mstats.kruskalwallis(array_samples, array_controls)
    kw_results.append(kw_test)
    n+=1
print(kw_results)
```

That gave `(1.0, 0.31731050786291404)` for all comparisons, even when I changed one of the lists drastically.

Digging deeper,  I read that the input should be a list of arrays, so I thought that giving only two datapoints (one sample, one control) might have caused the '(0.0, nan)', so I tried that as well.

```
controls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
samples = ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']
list_ = []
n=0
for item in controls:
    array_item = np.array([item, samples[n]])
    list_.append(array_item)
    n+=1
kw_test = stats.mstats.kruskalwallis(list_)
print(kw_test)
```

That gave me this error:

```
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Now I am not sure what format/type to use, hopefully anyone can help me out!

Answer (score 5):

The [scipy.stats.mstats.kruskalwallis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.kruskalwallis.html) module uses arrays. These can be arrays with an uneven number of observations.

If you have your data within a CSV file in separate columns, something like this should work:

```
import pandas
from scipy.stats import mstats

Data = pandas.read_csv("CSVfile.csv")
Col_1 = Data['Colname1']
Col_2 = Data['Colname2']
Col_3 = Data['Colname3']
Col_4 = Data['Colname4']

print("Kruskal Wallis H-test test:")

H, pval = mstats.kruskalwallis(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4)

print("H-statistic:", H)
print("P-Value:", pval)

if pval < 0.05:
    print("Reject NULL hypothesis - Significant differences exist between groups.")
if pval > 0.05:
    print("Accept NULL hypothesis - No significant difference between groups.")
```

Comment: i tried to do exactly like this but it gave error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SingleBlockManager'. any idea?

Comment: In my case no of columns is dynamic i can get 3-10 columns . How to handle this case

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason why the Kruskal Wallis test was giving the same p-value in all cases is because you are only comparing only two values in each case.

To pass a list of arrays to the kruskal test, it seems that you need to pass it as mstats.kruskalwallis(*args). See ([create vectors for Kruskal-Wallis H-test python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816865/create-vectors-for-kruskal-wallis-h-test-python))

```
import pandas, sys
from scipy.stats import mstats

H, pval = mstats.kruskalwallis(*args)
controls = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
samples = ['10', '20', '30', '70', '50']
n=0
kw_results = []
list_ = []
for item in controls:
    array_item = np.array([item, samples[n]])
    list_.append(array_item)
    n+=1
args=[l for l in list_]
kw_test =  mstats.kruskalwallis(*args)
print(kw_results)
```

If you have data in columns, Patrick's modification is useful but it didn't work for me to pass the list directly into the kruskal function but passing it *args worked.

```
import pandas, sys
from scipy.stats import mstats

Data = pandas.read_csv(sys.argv[1], index_col=0, sep='\t')
args = [Data[col] for col in Data.columns]
H, pval = mstats.kruskalwallis(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Osian's answer was of great help to me. I wanted to make this assume the first column was some sort of identifier, and not data and I also wanted to make the test assess all columns of data without manually entering the column headers. The following is a modification of Osian's code that met my criteria.

```
import pandas, sys
from scipy.stats import mstats

Data = pandas.read_csv(sys.argv[1], index_col=0, sep='\t')
H, pval = mstats.kruskalwallis([Data[col] for col in Data.columns])


print "H-statistic:\t%s\nP-value:\t%s" % (str(H),str(pval))
if pval < 0.05:
    print("Reject NULL hypothesis - Significant differences exist between groups.")
if pval > 0.05:
    print("Accept NULL hypothesis - No significant difference between groups.")
```