# create vectors for Kruskal-Wallis H-test python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kruskal-wallis

I have dataset as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':range(9), 'group':['a', 'b', 'c']*3})

 group numbers
0   a   0
1   b   1
2   c   2
3   a   3
4   b   4
5   c   5
6   a   6
7   b   7
8   c   8
```

i want to create vectors

```
a = [0, 3, 6]
b = [1, 4, 7]
c = [2, 5, 8]
```

for Kruskal-Wallis H-test python

```
stats.kruskal(a, b, c)
```

or maybe analogue as in R (numbers ~ group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with any special requirements of the Kruskal-Wallis test, but you can access these grouped arrays via by putting them into a dictionary this way:

```
groupednumbers = {}
for grp in df['group'].unique(): 
    groupednumbers[grp] = df['numbers'][df['group']==grp].values

print(groupednumbers)
*** {'c': array([2, 5, 8]), 'b': array([1, 4, 7]), 'a': array([0, 3, 6])}
```

That is, you'd get your vectors by either explicitly calling `groupednumbers['a']` etc., or via a list:

```
args = groupednumbers.values()
```

... or if you need them in an order:

```
args = [groupednumbers[grp] for grp in sorted(df['group'].unique())]
```

And then call

```
stats.kruskal(*args)
```

Or if you need actual lists, you can do `list(df['numbers'][...].values`.)

Comment: you can replace the first three lines with this more pythonic expression: `groupednumbers = {grp: df['numbers'][df['group']==grp].values for grp in df['group'].unique()}`